# Appsync graphql: How to filter based on entry in an array field

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

In my code I have created filter as:

> const myFilter: TableMyEntityFilterInput  = {targets: {contains: 'username'}};

'targets' field is an array:

> targets?: Array | null;

My objective is to fetch those records which has 'username' as an entry in 'targets' field.

But it does't work. Empty array is fetched. But if I use similar criteria on a simple string field, it works.

How to get it working for array field?

Edit:

'targets' sample value:

> [ { "S" : "[\"Messi\",\"Ronaldo\"]" }]

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a" can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.